# Mobile app gives 'the mapper function returned a null value' when I click on the excavator badge

Tags: bug, android-app

I clicked on the excavator badge I earned yesterday and found that it lead to this blank page with an error:

> The mapper function returned a null value

[image]

Comment: Development on the Apps is put on hold until further notice so unless this is a blocking bug that affects the majority of App users it won't be fixed.